# Powershell remotely register COM dll by using regsvr32

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I found on Internet, this ps script may work. But the result I get is: no error pops up, but also DLL not found in registry after running the script.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servername -ScriptBlock {regsvr32.exe "\\uncpath\some.dll" }
```

I tried in both "run as administrator" and normal PS console window, and windows remote management service is on on remote server.

Any idea?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend registering a DLL from a UNC path. That would mean that the remote computer would have to be available every time an app uses a component from the DLL. Try to describe the purpose/goal, rather than your attempted solution.

Comment: Hi Bill_Stewart, the purpose is move some files from current machine (which runs the script) to a remote server and then register a COM DLL on that remote machine. Basically, the script is like a installation tool.

Comment: The usual way of doing this is to consider the DLL as an application component and register it using a Windows Installer package (MSI). Even if the MSI only installs a single DLL, it can be assigned as a package and automatically installed via Group Policy.

Comment: If you are already copying files to the remote machine why not copy the DLL to the remote machine and within the remoting command use a path that is local to the remote machine e.g. `c:\some.dll`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the **silent** option of regsrv32 (`/s`):

> Syntax
>         REGSVR32 [/U] [/S] [/N] /I:[CommandLine] DLL_Name
>
> Key    /u          Unregister Server.
>
> /s          Silent, do not display dialogue boxes.
>
> /i          Call DllInstall to register the DLL.
>                  (when used with /u, it calls dll uninstall.)
>
> /n          Do not call DllRegisterServer, you must use this option
>   with /i.
>
> CommandLine  An optional command line for DllInstall
>
> /c          Console output (old versions only).